# Making user mandatorily fill a dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

My app flow:

App Launch ==> First Activity (Rich with options and Action bar buttons) ==> Login Dialog box

I need to enforce the login behavior.  As of now, users can press back button and bypass it.

My question is, how to detect on the activity class when user presses back button on the dialog and returns to the calling activity?  Otherwise, how can I enforce user to login and not proceed in the activity without it

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs show how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29). When you set cancelable to false the user cannot cancel the dialog (although the hardware search button will bypass this). You can also set a [Cancel Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the back button with this method: [setCancelabe(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29)

Comment: okay :)  That was because you pointed it out.  I figured it myself and revisited all my questions and accepted answers everywhere.  Thanks again.  I selected his answer over yours cuz he gave me a more elaborate answer with a second option of using Cancel Listener.  I'm sorry about that, Please dont mind